# how to config RegExp when string contains parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, parentheses

I'm sure this is an easy one, but I can't find it on the net.

This code:

```
    var new_html = "foo and bar(arg)";
    var bad_string = "bar(arg)";
    var regex = new RegExp(bad_string, "igm");
    var bad_start = new_html.search(regex);
```

sets bad_start to -1 (not found).  If I remove the (arg), it runs as expected (bad_start == 8).  Is there something I can do to make the (very handy) "new Regexp" syntax work, or do I have to find another way?  This example is trivial, but in the real app it would be doing global search and replace, so I need the regex and the "g".  Or do I?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the brackets by double back slashes \\. Try this.

```
    var new_html = "foo and bar(arg)";
    var bad_string = "bar\\(arg\\)";
    var regex = new RegExp(bad_string, "igm");
    var bad_start = new_html.search(regex);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/vQ8Jn/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your RegEx definition string should be:

```
var bad_string = "bar\\(arg\\)";
```

Special characters need to be escaped when using RegEx, and because you are building the RegEx in a string you need to escape your escape character :P

http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the special characters contained in string you are creating your Regex from. For example, define this function:

```js
function escapeRegex(string) {
  return string.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

And use it to assign the result to your `bad_string` variable:

```js
let bad_string = "bar(arg)"
bad_string = escapeRegex(bad_string)

// You can now use the string to create the Regex :v:
```